# Bots search for random links in search box

Tags: magento-1.7, search

Recently found that a few times/day links to odd websites that includes **Chinese symbols** show up in the **searched term field in the admin panel**

Basically bots automatically insert the link to weird website in the search box and these link show in Admin panel.

links look something like this: **XXXXXXXXX17363131312.com**
**X= random asian symbol.**

These links are not executable when searched on site. Any idea what could this be?

Comment: You mean searched term?

Comment: Yes, search terms, bots are inserting random link in the search term field... obviously there are not results on the site, but link still shows up as search term in the admin panel